# Background image inside DIV is repeated

Tags: javascript, image, repeat

I have a js animated div image which is repeated underneath. I've checked and edited the css a few times but it has not worked, i think it could be in this part of the js code I have supplied.  Could someone please tell me how to apply no-repeat to the js?

```
    {
            class Slide {
                constructor(el) {
                    this.DOM = {el: el};
                    this.DOM.slideImg = this.DOM.el.querySelector('.slide__img');
                    this.bgImage = this.DOM.slideImg.style.backgroundImage;
                    this.layout();
                }
                layout() {
                    this.DOM.slideImg.innerHTML = `<div class='glitch__img' style='background-image: ${this.DOM.slideImg.style.backgroundImage};'></div>`.repeat(5);
                    this.DOM.glitchImgs = Array.from(this.DOM.slideImg.querySelectorAll('.glitch__img'));
                }
                changeBGImage(bgimage, pos = 0, delay = 0) {
                    setTimeout(() => this.DOM.glitchImgs[pos].style.backgroundImage = bgimage, delay);
                }
            }
```

Comment: what is that .repeat(5) function call?

Comment: It's a glitch animated image which changes each time a button link is selected - hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript syntax to apply CSS background-repeat Property to an element is:

`object.style.backgroundRepeat= "no-repeat";`
in this case, `object` is the element to apply the property and value on.

Comment: OK I'll try that later, so whereabouts within the js code do I add it?

Comment: after sitting the background image itself

Answer (score 0):

If your `._slide_img` needs a `no-repeat`, you can just put that in the CSS?

CSS file

```
.slide_img {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

If that doesn't work there's probably something else in your code that prevents it. In that case please include all your code so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: OK, yes like I said I tried that but it didn't work.  I'll try the above js solution first then if no joy will post the css and part of the HTML - Thanks.